# Camel Saga: Coordinating a saga across two web-services

Tags: java, apache-camel, saga

I intend to use camel in-memory Saga in an integration project. There is a nice document about Saga with details. Is there some example code for in-memory Saga? I can use that to experiment with, for coordinating a saga across two SOAP-services, adding some integration test to validate etc.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/saga-eip.adoc

https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've recently created a workshop around the Saga pattern. It is using the in-memory saga with REST endpoints, but any kind of endpoint can be used with it, including SOAP services.

The most important requirement (for using the in-memory saga) is that each "action endpoint" has a corresponding "compensating endpoint".

You can find slides and code here: https://github.com/nicolaferraro/camel-workshop